# Can I use an off the shelf electromagnetic lock to repel?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics

Can I take an off the shelf electromagnetic lock such as this [https://www.amazon.com/SKYZONAL-Electric-Magnetic-Electromagnet-Fail-Safe/dp/B01LE95P7I/ref=sr_1_11?keywords=electromagnet&qid=1583007323&sr=8-11&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LE95P7I) and use it to repel rather than attract? Can I vary the current to affect the magnetic field strength?

Based on the information provided, I can't tell whether there is some special circuitry built in that only allows it to be on or off, or only allows the current to flow one way in these types of devices. I am looking for a moderately powerful electromagnet for a project and I need it to repel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electromagnet with iron core seems to attract strong neodymium magnet when I want to repel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483585/electromagnet-with-iron-core-seems-to-attract-strong-neodymium-magnet-when-i-wan)

Comment: What you want is something similar to a voicecoil, where you have a coil and a magnet. Depending on how the coil is energized it will attract or repel the magnet. You could do the same with two coils, also. The alternative would be use a solenoid to actually make contact with the object to be repelled, if that is acceptable.

Comment: it says there's a "voltage spike supressor" in there. if that's a diode (which is the cheapest option) the the electromaget will ony work with one polarity.

Comment: what are you trying to repel?

Comment: The problem is the same as in your previous question. The magnet is designed to attract anything that will close the flux path between the outer and inner poles of the magnet. One polarity of applied current makes the outer edge pieces north and the center piece south, and the opposite polarity does the reverse. If you had a permanent with the same shape and physically prevent it from moving sideways it could be repelled, but only from a fairly short distance.